# How to import csv file from the link in gmail to google sheet with apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just want to import CSV. file from the link in specific gmail to google sheet automatically by using Apps script.
But I only got some examples about attachment, not link.
The Gmail that I want to import has the URL link which is the link for downloading CSV file.
Is there any possibility?

Comment: There are many possibilities. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. I suggest you to start by focusing on searching your email mailbox, then proceed to parse the message content, then to extract the link, etc. If you get stuck at some point, edit the question to make it specific about where get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Google Sheets spreadsheet, and type into a cell =IMPORTDATA("URL") where URL is the link containing the CSV file. Read more [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335?hl=en) from Google's help page.

Comment: oh, but I want to search the specific mail with google apps script and extract the data of URL and import it automatically and directly.